# how to check the django objects filter get something

Tags: python, django

here is my code

```
        for add in Address.objects.filter(city_id='112'):
            print add
            if add:
                print 'ok,I got something'
            else:
                print 'nothing found'
```

When it filter somrthing,it will print :

```
Address object 
ok.Igot something
```

But when it didn't filter something,

`print add` show nothing,and it didn't print `'nothing found'`

I want to ask how to check the Address.objects.filter() get object

Answer (score 3):

In boolean context queryset returns `True` if it is not empty and `False` is nothing is found:

```
address_list = Address.objects.filter(city_id='112')
if address_list:
    print 'ok,I got something'
    for address in address_list:
        print address
else:
    print 'nothing found'
```

If you use queryset in the template then the [{% for %} ... {% empty %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) template tag can help you:

```
<ul>
    {% for address in address_list %}
        <li>{{ address }}</li>
    {% empty %}
        <li>Nothing found</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

When `Address.objects.filter(city_id='112')` returns an empty array, your `for` loop is skipped entirely.  Your `if` is inside that loop, so when nothing is returned, no other code is hit at all.